# Displaying predicted values of 'y' with corresponding actual 'x' values in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am attempting to write a neural network that uses 100 data points evenly spaced along a y = sin(x) graph, between 0 and (5/2)pi. So the x values go from 0 to 7.854, and the corresponding y values oscillate between 1 and -1.

I have split the data into training and validation points, and it seems to have trained properly, however when I try to print the 'test' data, it is 100% correct, no matter how many neurons, epochs that I use. I think it is simply displaying the actual values, no predictions.

I think that I must have done something wrong in the final predictions part of the code, but I am not sure how to display the predicted values of y by the network for corresponding x values. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation
import pandas as pd
import io
import os
import requests
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Dan\\Desktop\\UNI\\PROJECT\\y_sinx_values.csv")

x = df['x'].values 
y = df['y'].values

# Split into training and validation sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_shape = (1,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam')

monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3, patience=1, verbose=1, mode='auto', restore_best_weights=True)
model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),callbacks=[monitor],verbose=2, epochs=2)

pred = model.predict(x_test)
score = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(pred,y_test))
print(f"Final score (RMSE): {score}")

# Sample predictions
for i in range(25):
    print(f"{i+1}. x: {x_test[i]}, y: {y_test[i]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Sample predictions
for i in range(25):
    print(f"{i+1}. x: {x_test[i]}, y: {y_test[i]}")
```

Yes, you are printing your input test data. You most likely want something like:

```py
# Sample predictions
for i in range(25):
    print(f"{i+1}. x: {x_test[i]}, y: {pred[i]}")
```

Note the `y_test[i]` has been changed to `pred[i]`.

Comment: That gives me all small decimal numbers for y, there must be something else wrong?

Comment: Not necessarily, how well does your model perform in the first place? How about you run `model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)` and print out your results from that?